# Hide image on hover - SCSS

Tags: css, image, sass, hover

I'm trying to hide my image so that it reveals the one behind it, whenever I hover on the button. For some reason, I can't get it working - I feel like my code should work. I've tried doing display:none and block for the hover and even tried the z-index but I still can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

I currently have text hidden that reveals when I hover the button, so I'm not sure if that is affecting it. But i've done that is SCSS.

```
<figure class="figure">

              <img class="figure-image lazyload front"
                src="/image.png">

                <img class="figure-image lazyload back"
                src="/image2.png">


   <button class="figure-button" id="figure-button">REVEAL ANSWER</button>
    <figcaption class="figure-caption-test" id="reveal-text">HiddenText</figcaption>

            </figure>
```

My SCSS -

```
.figure-button:hover + .figure-caption-test {
      display: block;
    }


    .back {
      opacity: 1;
    }


    .figure-button:hover + .back {
      opacity: 0!important;
    }
```

JsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/2ukxfe47/1/

Comment: Selector `+` is to select the next element after the current one. so when you are setting: `.figure-button:hover + .back` it is searching for a sibling element with class `.back` right after `.figure-button`. This is why it works fine with `.figure-caption-test`. There is no "previous" selector in CSS. So you must to change your html if you want to do so in CSS only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the position of the button in the mark-up

```
<figure class="figure">
<button class="figure-button" id="figure-button">REVEAL ANSWER</button>
              <img class="figure-image lazyload front"
                src="/image.png">

                <img class="figure-image lazyload back"
                src="/image2.png">


   
    <figcaption class="figure-caption-test" id="reveal-text">HiddenText</figcaption>

            </figure>
```

As well as replace the selector + with ~ (This selector will select all siblings after `.figure-button` that have the class `.figure-caption-test`)

```
.figure-button:hover ~ .figure-caption-test {
      display: block;
    }


    .back {
      opacity: 1;
    }


    .figure-button:hover ~ .back {
      opacity: 0!important;
    }
```

'+' is targeting the very next element you add after it. See more here : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp